# How to set up debugger for ARM Assembly using qemu and gdb

Tags: compiling, virtualization, arm, qemu, gdb

I followed this [tutorial](http://doppioandante.github.io/2015/07/10/Simple-ARM-programming-on-linux.html) as well as this [one](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2010979) to set up a compiler + debugger for ARM Assembly.

Following the first one, I ran the command `qemu-arm -singlestep -g 1234 empty`and started a new shell, where I tried to conncet gdb to qemu by copy&pasting the given instructions :

`➜ arm-none-eabi-gdb
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.9.1
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later > <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --target=arm-none-eabi".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
(gdb) file empty
Reading symbols from empty...done.
(gdb) target remote localhost:1234
Remote debugging using localhost:1234
_start () at empty.s:4
4       mov r0, #1
(gdb)`

However whenever I try to connect with `target remote localhost:1234` there's a time-out error.
I also followed the instructions in the second tutorial, but ended with the same time-out error. Do I need to pre-configure qemu ?